# Difference in handling xml string between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-chrome, firefox

I am having some trouble with parsing an XML string I get from ajax request in the two browsers. In Chrome when I do

```
totalResults = parseInt($(data).find("totalResults").text());
```

I get a value, however in Firefox I get 'NaN' when the same piece of code gets executed.

Data is reported to be an 'object' by .type(data) in both browsers. Anyone knows how I can get a value of that in both browsers? Been completely stumped by this for a few days now :(

### Edit:

Some code examples:

```
function getAllProgrammes()
        {
           requestAll().done(function (items) {
              console.log(items, $.parseXML(items));
              $(items).find('entry').each(function () {
                 programme = parseProgramme($(this));
                 $programmesData.push(programme);
              });

              // Now we can parse all the data and create a list :)
              parseProgrammesData($programmesData);
              $("#found").append('Found ' + $totalCount + ' programmes');
           });
           return;
```

This then calls requestall

```
function requestAll() {
           return requestItems(1, 999, []);
        }

function requestItems(pageStart, pageEnd, items) {
           return request(pageStart, pageEnd).then(function (data) {
              totalResults = parseInt($(data).find("totalResults").text());
              console.log('total ', totalResults, ' xml ', $.type(data));
              if (pageEnd > totalResults || isNaN(totalResults)) {
                 return items;
              } else {
                 $("div#status").html('Loading events from ' + pageEnd + ' to ' + totalResults);
                 return requestItems(pageEnd, pageEnd + 999, items.concat(data));
              }
           });
        }
```

And request simply does the ajax call

```
function request(pageStart, pageEnd) {
           $requestParams['startindex'] = pageStart;
           $requestParams['endindex'] = pageEnd;

           return $.ajax({
              url: "http://blahurl",
              method: 'GET',
              dataType: 'xml',
              data: $.param($requestParams)
           });
        }
```

---

The area I was asking about is this console.log: console.log('total ', totalResults, ' xml ', $.type(data));

In firefox it gives me "total " NaN " xml " "object" while in chrome total  1867  xml  object

So I wanted to extract the information I need from this.

```
<atom:feed xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:yv="url"><atom:id>someid</atom:id><atom:link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="request&startindex=1&amp;endindex=999"/><atom:title>search</atom:title><atom:updated>2015-04-17T13:22:36Z</atom:updated><atom:author><atom:name>name</atom:name><atom:uri>uri</atom:uri></atom:author><os:totalResults>2010</os:totalResults><os:startIndex>1</os:startIndex><os:itemsPerPage>999</os:itemsPerPage>
```

I wanted to extract things like  from it and other things like these, but I am not too familiar with xml parsing in JS.

Comment: Can you post an example of such XML string?

Comment: Please post more of your code to give a little more context. Also, it is expected that your data is an 'object' - it is the most basic form in javascript. Have you done anything to dig deeper into this? Do both browsers correctly find "totalResults"? Maybe try printing it to the javascript console and inspecting it by hand.

Comment: Hiya, sorry I posted the code and the sample xml, appreciate the help :)

Also when I run the same in IE - it hangs at the ajax call instead and does not even make the call. Ie I cannot find it in the network bar at all, any ideas?